# Apache Solr caching <-> stress test

Tags: apache, caching, solr

I want to do a quick&dirt load testing - but all my results are cached.
I commented out all the Solr caches - but still everything is cached.

- Can the caching come from the 'Field Collapsing Cache'.
  -- although I don't see this element in my config file.
  ( As the system now jumps from 1GB to 7 GB of RAM when I do a load
  test with lots of queries ).
- Can it be a Lucence cache?

+-----------------------------------------------------+
I want to lower the caches so they cache only some 100 or 1000 documents.
( Right now - when I do 50 000 unique queries Solr will use 7 GB of
RAM and everything fits in some cache! )

Any suggestions how I could proper stress test my Solr - with a small
number of queries (some 100 0000 - not in the millions as some testers
have)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not a recommended praxis. your results won't be realistic. it is even very important to tune the cache settings!

Try to hit solr with queries build from log files.
I'm using fastbench for that kind of testing but you can use jmeter, a bash script or sth. similar

> Can it be a Lucence cache?

yes

> Field Collapsing Cache

no, you'll need the patch + config for that

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I'm aware of the power of the cache.
I just want to limit the intern caches - so I don't need millions of test queries. 

I want to lower the caches - so that I can test the system with only 100 000 unique queries without a cache hit of 99%! ).

How do you do such thing?
Or can you give me more info about the patch&config you mention?

Comment: Or can I give my Solr config less memory ( now its 7.5 GB ) - so the cache can save less results in its caches?
Or will this badly affect performance?

Comment: ah. ok I understand. Indeed this could be a possibilty, but I am not sure if the systems will be comparable. we do stress testing on lower equipped machines and then try the new feature or core partially on production to be sure that this will scale. Where partially means only 10% or 20% of the user will get/see this ...

Comment: @Karussell, the patch you are referring to, is that a patch to add field collapsing cache, or just field collapsing?

Comment: Field Collapsing is already in the released Solr version as of today. No patch necessary. To tune it you'll have to consult the Solr Docs for field collapsing and tuning of Solr in general (as well as lucene+jvm tuning)